# How can I solve the error of using python extension in Netlogo?

Tags: python-3.x, netlogo

I am trying to test the extension of python in Netlogo agent based modeling :

this my code :

```
extensions [py] 
to setup


  py:setup py:python

  show py:runresult "1 + 1"
end
```

and I got this error :

```
Python error output:
C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.1.0\app\extensions\py\pyext.py:8: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
  from collections import Mapping
```

I need help, thank very much.

Comment: That's just a warning, not a "real" error, so you can ignore it as long as you aren't using Python 3.8.  It should not affect any of the results of running your code, it'll just output that message when you start your model.  It's a known issue as reported on the Python-Extension GitHub repository:  https://github.com/NetLogo/Python-Extension/issues/14

Comment: Thank you Jasper for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Download the last version of netlogo: netlogo 6.1.1

Comment: This should be a comment.